# Android, register for Otto events outside of Fragments / Activities?

Tags: android, otto

Otto works great when used in Activities or Fragments, but can I subscribe to events in classes that don't have a `onPause` / `onResume` / `onDestroy` method? If so, what's the best practice to `unregister`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otto doesn't have a method to check whether an object has been registered or not. That's why best practices say you should better use one of the lifecycle methods you mentioned.

If you register outside of these methods you could define a `boolean` field and set it to `true` if you have already registered an object. If this field is `true` you don't need to register it again. Don't forget to unregister it when you are done with this object (e.g. in `Activity.onDestroy()` you can post a message for unregistering all such instances).

You can also check out [TinyBus](https://github.com/beworker/tinybus) library, which has extended Otto interfaces. There is also `Bus.hasRegistered(Obejct)` method, which can be used to check whether an object has been registered in the bus or not. It also provides Wireable API for components, which listen to `Activity` lifecycle and can register or unregister themselves when a bus instance attached to an `Activity` gets destroyed.